# How to understand "Available Data Objects" in CAP theorem?

Tags: distributed-computing, cap-theorem

In "Brewer’s Conjecture and the Feasibility of Consistent, Available,  Partition-Tolerant Web Services", it says

```
For a distributed system to be continuously available, every request received
by a non-failing node in the system must result in a response
```

So in a system such as a zookeeper cluster or MongoDB replica set, in which the only master can accept write request, if clients send a write request to a slave, it will redirect clients to master or reject the request.
In this case, it that true that request received by slave results in a response?
And why zookeeper is always called the CP system without A?

I have read [How to understand the "Availability" of the CAP theorem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069147/how-to-understand-the-availability-of-the-cap-theorem), but did not get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> In this case, it that true that request received by slave results in a response?

I think that availability should be treated as an ability to have request **successfully** handled at some point in future. In your examples you're considering databases with single possible master, so in your case, if the master goes down, slave can response only with an error. Since it's not a successful response, it's not enough to fit availability (`A`) clause.

Comment: Even if the master goes well, slave can only response write request with rejection, does this count a  request handled **successfully**?

Comment: @Tim If you mean situation when client sends write response to the read-only replica, that's just a bad request. It's client's fault or balancer misbehavior (because it must route write requests to master replicas).